# PHPExcel: Read Excel File Line by Line

Tags: php, phpexcel, netbeans-8

I need some help. What I am trying to achieve is to read Excel file line by line using PHPExcel. I am able to read the file and also get the data, but can't figure it out how to read it line by line. Here is my code.

```
require_once ('../src/Classes/PHPExcel.php');

    $excel_path = '../' . $_SESSION['excel_path'];

    try {
        $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($excel_path);
        $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($excel_path);
        $excelObject = $excelReader->load($excel_path);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        die('Error loading file"' . pathinfo($excel_path, PATHINFO_BASENAME) . '": ' . $ex->getMessage());
    }

    $sheet = $excelObject->getSheet(0);
    $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
    $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
        $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . 
                $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
        foreach ($rowData as $k) {
            echo $k[0].'<br />';
        }
    }       
    ?
```

I was that someone could help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code in place of your for loop

```
$rows = $sheet->rangetoArray('A1:'.$highestColumn . $highestRow, NULL, True, True, False);
foreach ($rows as $row => $cols) {      
    $line = '';
    foreach($cols as $col => $cell){
        $line .= $cell." ... "; // ... or some other separator
    }
    echo rtrim($line,'. ').'<br />';
 }
```

**Edited To add {} around inner foreach loop**

**Edited: Adding 2nd option - for creating tabular data**

This works for me and creates a table, using the excel sheet name as the table caption

```
$sheetname = $sheet->getTitle();
$start=1;
$table = "<table><caption>$sheetname</caption>";
$rows = $sheet->rangetoArray('A'.$start.':'.$highestColumn . $highestRow, NULL, True, True, False);
foreach ($rows as $row => $cols) {      
    $line = '<tr class="'.$row.'">';
    foreach($cols as $col => $cell){
        $line .= "<td>".$cell."</td>"; // ... or some other separator           
    }
    if($row == 0) $line = str_replace("td>","th>", $line);
    $table .= $line.'</tr>';
 } 
$table .= "</table>";.

echo $table;
```

Comment: Hey I did that, and and it's printing it three time. Example: If I have "Roanoke VA 24010" one line 1. It will print out Roanoke and on the next line it will print out Roanoke VA, and one third line it will print out Roanoke VA, 24010

Comment: It sounds like it is exiting the second foreach loop before completing the lines contents . I have edited my answer to enclose the 2nd foreach in {}s